# Can I use eclipse JDT/AST for other programming languages?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

Can I use the AST / JDT for other languages? For example to write my own parser for C# that uses somehow the AST technology?

Comment: If you "just" need to debug C#, I believe there is a good debugger available for Mono on non-windows platforms.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the article "[Eclipse JDT - Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and the Java Model - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html)", JDT and its AST are tailored for Java.

> The Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT) provide APIs to access and manipulate Java source code.
>   The AST is a detailed tree representation of Java source code. The AST defines API to modify, create, read and delete source code.
>   The package for AST is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom` in the Eclipse `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin.

Other AST exists for [other languages](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/eclipse-much-more-java), and for generating your own, you could use **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**

[alt text http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/images/screenshot-title.png](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/images/screenshot-title.png)

But the one in a jdt package is speicialized for Java.
It can be viewed through an [ASTView](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php)

[image]

See also the [Exploring Eclipse's ASTParser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ast/) article as another illustration of the Java-oriented aspect of eclipse AST manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use JDT for other languages(unless you define an embedded grammar, see comments from Mark), it is for Java only as its name indicates. If you want to build a parser for C#, [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) is a nice tool which can give you a visible tree after feeding in the grammar. [Here](http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/) is a grammar used in Antlr for C#.

Comment: You can extend JDT for custom java-like languages: http://blog.objectteams.org/2010/02/ide-for-your-own-language-embedded-in-java-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, and the article your referred is interesting. He asked if JDT can be used for another language. Technically, yes, I agree like this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750995/antlr-is-it-possible-to-make-grammar-with-embed-grammar-inside), but I think the cost is high, since he only wants to process one language.

Answer (score 0):

you May use ANTLR(ANother Tool for Language Recognition) it is a very powerful that generates lexer and parser out from your grammar file. the good news is that you will find open source grammar files available on github.
https://www.antlr.org/
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

You will need to create your own AST model.