# ANTLR Is it possible to make grammar with embed grammar inside?

Tags: antlr, grammar

ANTLR: Is it possible to make grammar with embed grammar (with it's own lexer) inside?

For example in my language I have ability to use embed SQL language:

```
var Query = [select * from table];
with Query do something ....;
```

Is it possible with ANTLR?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to make grammar with embed grammar (with it's own lexer) inside?

If you mean whether it is possible to define two languages in a single grammar (using separate lexers), then the answer is: no, that's not possible.

However, if the question is whether it is possible to parse two languages into a single AST, then the answer is: yes, it is possible.

You simply need to:

- define both languages in their own grammar;
- create a lexer rule in you main grammar that captures the entire input of the embedded language;
- use a rewrite rule that calls a custom method that parses the external AST and inserts it in the main AST using `{` ... `}` (see the `expr` rule in the main grammar (`MyLanguage.g`)).

#### MyLanguage.g

```java
grammar MyLanguage;

options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
}

@members {
  private CommonTree parseSQL(String sqlSrc) {
    try {
      MiniSQLLexer lexer = new MiniSQLLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(sqlSrc));
      MiniSQLParser parser = new MiniSQLParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      return (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      return new CommonTree(new CommonToken(-1, e.getMessage()));
    }
  }
}

parse
  :  assignment+ EOF -> ^(ROOT assignment+)
  ;

assignment
  :  Var Id '=' expr ';' -> ^('=' Id expr)
  ;

expr
  :  Num
  |  SQL -> {parseSQL($SQL.text)}
  ;

Var   : 'var';
Id    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Num   : '0'..'9'+;
SQL   : '[' ~']'* ']';
Space : ' ' {skip();};
```

#### MiniSQL.g

```java
grammar MiniSQL;

options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

parse
  :  '[' statement ']' EOF -> statement
  ;

statement
  :  select
  ;

select
  :  Select '*' From ID -> ^(Select '*' From ID)
  ;

Select : 'select';
From   : 'from';
ID     : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
Space  : ' ' {skip();};
```

#### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String src = "var Query = [select * from table]; var x = 42;";
    MyLanguageLexer lexer = new MyLanguageLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(src));
    MyLanguageParser parser = new MyLanguageParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

#### Run the demo

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool MiniSQL.g 
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool MyLanguage.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

Given the input:

```
var Query = [select * from table]; var x = 42;
```

the output of the `Main` class corresponds to the following AST:

[image]

And if you want to allow string literals inside your SQL (which could contain `]`), and comments (which could contain `'` and `]`), the you could use the following `SQL` rule inside your main grammar:

```java
SQL
  :  '[' ( ~(']' | '\'' | '-')
         | '-' ~'-' 
         | COMMENT 
         | STR
         )* 
     ']'
  ;

fragment STR 
  :  '\'' (~('\'' | '\r' | '\n') | '\'\'')+ '\'' 
  |  '\'\''
  ;

fragment COMMENT
  :  '--' ~('\r' | '\n')*
  ;
```

which would properly parse the following input in a single token:

```sql
[
  select a,b,c 
  from table 
  where a='A''B]C' 
  and b='' -- some ] comment ] here'
]
```

Just beware that trying to create a grammar for an entire SQL dialect (or even a large subset) is no trivial task! You may want to search for existing SQL parsers, or look at the ANTLR wiki for example-grammars.

Comment: Would it be the same answer for antlr4 or would antlr4 simplify it grammar-wise?

Comment: @Andrei with ANTLR4 you could use lexical modes  to make this kind of thing easier: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes

Comment: Is it possible to include lexer tokens for a given mode (say I have Java embedded in XML) so that my Java tokens won't interfere with XML tokens?

Comment: I don”t know what you mean by “interfere”. Token names are unique, so can never interfere with each other.

Comment: I mean that the java tokens have to be "declared" only in the "mode Java" section of the grammar. If you declare the "IF : 'if';" token at the beginning of XMLLexer, it will break the parser. So I was wondering if you can only manually copy/paste tokens from JavaLexer to the "mode Java" section of the XMLLexer or there is a better way (some sort of "include" in the mode).

Comment: No, there is no “include” feature in lexer modes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with AntLR it is called *Island grammar*.
You can get a working example in the [v3 examples](http://www.antlr.org/download/examples-v3.tar.gz), inside the island-grammar folder : it shows the usage of a grammar to parse javadoc comments inside of java code.

You can also find some clues in the doc [Island Grammars Under Parser Control](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control) and that [Another one](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Another+solution+for+Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control).

Comment: It seems like AntLR has no built in ability to parse nested grammars. In your example there are couple of tricks including semantics predicates and editing generated parser and lexer. Seems like everething is bad here... I think in this case more correct answer would be "No. AntLR has no built in ability to do this but there are couple of tricks that work sometimes..."

Comment: @Astronavigator : I am sorry, I understood the first line of your question as "is it possible to parse mixed languages with AntLR" (which indeed is possible) and not "it it possible to describe mixed languages in the same grammar" (which is not built-in - at least in v3). As you noticed, you need to define some start and end points to let your parser know where to switch between languages. The "island" grammar is just another regular grammar that is called with selected pieces of the input flow.